# Prefix OAuth properties ? i.e. as:client_id

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt, claims

I am seeing a lot of people using "as" as a prefix for return items on OAuth for example

```
   as:client_id
```

Can anyone tell me what significance this has?

I don't see it in the OAuth specs

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the examples that I found([Adding Refresh Tokens to a Web API v2 Authorization Server](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/15/adding-refresh-tokens-to-a-web-api-v2-authorization-server/), [OAuth Resource Password Flow Refresh Token with Web Api](http://timney.net/oauth-resource-password-flow-refresh-token-with-web-api/)) that's just an example "key" to store the `client_id` in a dictionary local to the client for later usage.

By no means it is used in the interaction with the Authorization Server or as part of the OAuth 2.0 protocol itself.